# cannot find module "react"

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, module

I am using react inside my django application but now I am facing this `error.module not found` but module is there.

`package.json`

```json
    {
    "name": "lead-manager",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch ./leadmanager/frontend/src/index.js --output-path ./leadmanager/frontend/static/frontend/main.js",
        "build": "webpack --mode production ./leadmanager/frontend/src/index.js --output-path ./leadmanager/frontend/static/frontend/main.js"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.3",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "webpack": "^5.74.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
    }
}
```

and `App.js` is following where console show me error

```js
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
    import Header from "./layout/Header";
    import Dashboard from "./leads/Dashboard";
    
    const App = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Dashboard />
            </div>
        );
    };
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app"));
    root.render(<App />);
```

and project tree is following

```
    ├

    ── src
    │   │   ├── components
    │   │   │   ├── App.js
    │   │   │   ├── Form.jsx
    │   │   │   ├── layout
    │   │   │   │   └── Header.js
    │   │   │   ├── leads
    │   │   │   │   └── Dashboard.jsx
    │   │   │   └── Leads.jsx
    │   │   └── index.js
    │   ├── static
    │   │   ├── css
    │   │   │   └── style.css
    │   │   └── frontend
    │   │       └── main.js
    │   │           └── main.js
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   └── frontend
    │   │       └── index.html
```

according to my knowledge path is correct. Everything is fine `Header` component is working and `Dashboard` is not working.

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: not working sir

Comment: Please show your project tree from the root folder of your project

Answer (score 1):

Did you install npm? It is major issue with npm installation. try out this in local directory

```
   npm install
```

Comment: yes i have done it but not working